# Finding the number of matrices up to similarity with characteristic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find the number of similar matrices with characteristic polynomial  $(x-1)^4(x-2)^3(x-3)^2$

$(x-1)^4$ can have the following forms

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$

$(x-2)^3$ can have

$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 2\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 2\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 2\\
 \end{pmatrix}$

and $(x-3)^2$ can have

$\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 1\\
  0 & 3\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $
$\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 0\\
  0 & 3\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\hspace {10pt} $

I multiplied $4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$ to get my answer, but I read an answer from this question [Classify up to similarity all complex $3 \times 3$ matrices A such that A such that ${A^3} = 2{A^2} - A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014370/classify-up-to-similarity-all-complex-3-times-3-matrices-a-such-that-a-such-t) and says it becomes a problem for Jordan blocks size greater than 3. How would I approach this when the matrix is greater than $3$?

Comment: You forgot the case of two Jordan blocks of size $2$.

Comment: @Bernard ooh, so would the be $5 \times 3 \times 2 = 30 $ ?

Comment: I think so. You just have to count the number of partitions of the integer $4$

Comment: @Bernard thank you! So the general way to solve these is to find the number of partitions for each factor then multiply them?

Comment: That's right. I mean the number of partitions for each multiplicity ($>1$ since for simple factors there's not much to compute…)